# Hide footer on multi page jQuery Mobile web app

Tags: javascript, jquery, navbar, footer

I have a jQuery Mobile page ([Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Loqgubqj/)) which loads an external footer like so:

```
<!-- Start of universal footer -->
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabOne">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabTwo">Two</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /End of universal footer -->

<!-- Start of first page -->
<div data-role="page" id="tabOne">
    <div data-role="header">Page 1</div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">Content</div>
</div>
<!-- /End of first page -->

<!-- Start of second page -->
<div data-role="page" id="tabTwo">
    <div data-role="header">Page 2</div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">Content</div>
</div>
<!-- /End of second page -->
```

With some js:

```
$(function() {
    $("[data-role='navbar']").navbar();
    $("[data-role='footer']").toolbar({theme: "a"});
});
```

This is all working perfectly, but I'd like to have another page (a login page which displays first) which doesn't show the footer (or shows an alternate one) but I can't seem to make that happen. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you after something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/Loqgubqj/1/

Comment: Awesome @LegenJerry! I can definitely get that to do what I need. Thanks!